# How do I add custom anchor links with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, anchor, greasemonkey

I want to add new anchor links to a page using Greasemonkey.  Specifically, I want to add custom smileys so that I don't have to find the smiley image and  copy-and-paste the link into an `[img]` tag every time.

The code I want to add is this

```
<a href="#" onclick="insert_text(':D', true); return false;">
    <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_biggrin.gif" alt=":D" title="Very Happy" height="17" width="15">
</a>
```

but I want to change the img src location and the onclick to something like

```
insert_text('[img]imagesourcelocation[/img]' ,true) return false;
```

The `[img]` source would be the same as the image URL.
I want to be able to add many smileys over time -- changing the `alt` and `title` attributes would be great too, but I need mainly the other two.

How would I do this?
So far all I have is this:

```
var para=document.createElement("a");
var node=document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element=document.getElementById("smiley-box");
element.appendChild(para);
```

As you can see, I need to add this new smiley to the `<div>` with the id `smiley-box`.

If anyone can help me do this I would be so happy.

Comment: you have a space `document.createElement("a ");` also anchors need an `href`, e.g: `para.href = '#'`

Comment: that dosent help as i dont know how to change all this with js if you could give me a exaple of how to add a anchor like the first code i show so i can edit it to my liking that be great

Answer (score 1):

You can set the properties of DOM element objects by accessing their attributes, e.g. to set the href:

```
para.href = "#";
```

Setting the onclick is a bit different - instead of giving it a string of Javascript, you give it a function:

```
para.onclick = function() {
    insert_text('[img]imagesourcelocation[/img]' ,true);
    return false;
}
```

To achieve the image in a link, just create an img element instead of a text node, set it's attributes like above, and add it to the link:

```
// create the img and set it's src
var node=document.createElement("img");
node.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Smiley.png/50px-Smiley.png"

// add the img to the anchor
para.appendChild(node);
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/d2gGR/

References:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_anchor.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: thanks that helps me understand the basics i just figured i could do something ill post my answer to what i have done.Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the greasemoney way but you could also just update the innerHTML of the smiley box directly

```
function add(url, alt, title)
{
    var box=document.getElementById("smiley-box");
    box.innerHTML += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"insert_text('[img]" + url + 
                     "[/img]', true); return false;\"><img src=\"" + url + 
                     "\" alt=\"" + alt + "\" title=\"" + title + "\" height=\"17\" width=\"15\"></a>";
}
```

You can then add smileys to the box like this (link, alt text and title text):

```
add("http://bit.ly/1a4xaTX",":D","Big grin");
add("http://bit.ly/HDGdlw",":(","Sad");
add("http://bit.ly/175LywW",":O","Surprised");
```

jingtao's solution is a nice one though.

Comment: No! [Don't manipulate `innerHTML` on existing page elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462990/331508) except in certain rare situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's **a complete script** that adds custom smilies using the awesome power of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Note that it avoids 3 of the deadly sins of scripting:

1. It avoids ["cut and paste (and cry)" coding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).
2. It uses event handlers the robust web 2.0 way. (Never use `onclick`.)
3. It does not trash `innerHTML` of existing elements.

Additionally, this code is very easy to make AJAX-aware, if needed, using [waitForKeyElements()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add custom smilies
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
$("#smiley-box").append ('<p>Custom smileys.</p>');

addNewSmiley ("http://sguwars.com/forum/images/smilies/icon_cool.gif");

function addNewSmiley (imageURL) {
    $("#smiley-box").append (
        '<a href="#" class="gmCustomSmilies">'
        + '<img src="' + imageURL + '"></a>'
    );
}

//-- Activate click handlers for any and all of our custom smilies
$(document.body).on ("click", "a.gmCustomSmilies", insertSmilie);

function insertSmilie (evnt) {
    var jThis   = $(evnt.target);
    var imgURL  = jThis.find ("img").attr ("src");

    unsafeWindow.insert_text ('[img]' + imgURL + '[/img]', true);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var para=document.createElement("p");
var node=document.createTextNode("custom smileys.");
para.appendChild(node);
links = document.createElement('a');
links.setAttribute('href','#');
links.setAttribute('onclick','insert_text(\'[img]http://sguwars.com/forum/images/smilies/icon_cool.gif[/img]\', true); return false;');
links.innerHTML ='<a href="we.html"><img src="http://sguwars.com/forum/images/smilies/icon_cool.gif" /></a>';
var element=document.getElementById("smiley-box");

element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(links);
```

this is my solution so far thankyou